# EF-Core Migration ignore Max Length

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on .net core 6 along with EF-Core 7. I have define config class for the model where I have define `HasMaxLength`. When I run migration on ef core, it ignore the string length. I have also tried with `.HasColumnType("nvarchar(80)` but still no luck; not sure what I missing here?

Incorrect length based on config

```
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "JobProfiles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                JobProfileId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                SourceServer = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                SourceDirectory = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                DestinationServer = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                DestinationDirectory = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
            },
```

Model

```
public class JobProfile
{
    public Guid JobProfileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SourceServer { get; set; }
    public string SourceDirectory { get; set; }
    public string DestinationServer { get; set; }
    public string DestinationDirectory { get; set; }
}
```

Config

```
public class JobProfileConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JobProfile>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<JobProfile> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("JobProfile", "dbo");

        builder.HasKey(column => column.JobProfileId);

        builder.Property(c => c.Name)
          .IsRequired()
          .HasColumnType("nvarchar(80)");
            

        builder.Property(c => c.SourceServer)
          .IsRequired()
          .HasMaxLength(350);

        builder.Property(c => c.SourceDirectory)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

        builder.Property(c => c.DestinationServer)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(350);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use annotation in dotnet like this -

Column annotation can be used in multiple purpose. It's one of them.

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(max)")]
public string SourceDirectory { get; set; }
```

You can also use fluent api -

```
builder.Property(obj => obj.SourceDirectory.IsMaxLength());
```

Comment: I don't want to use data annotation and that is why I have config class separate

Comment: You can use IsMaxLength as well. I updated my comment. please look into this. hope it will work. @K.Z

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[Table("JobProfile")]
public class JobProfile
{
    [Key]
    public Guid JobProfileId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(350)]
    [Required]
    public string SourceServer { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SourceDirectory { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(350)]
    [Required]
    public string DestinationServer { get; set; }
    public string DestinationDirectory { get; set; }
}
```

You could also add more annotations which is neater than configure it inside the builder in my opinion

Comment: I want to use fluent api

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but I had the same issue. Don't forget to apply your **JobProfileConfiguration** inside **OnModelCreating** method on your context.

```
builder.ApplyConfiguration(new JobProfileConfiguration());
```